# inserting into mongodb using bash

Tags: bash, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a collection into a database using bash. So far this is what i've come up with.

```
mongo --port 27000 --eval "rs.status().members.forEach(function(m) { if(m.stateStr === \'PRIMARY\') {var t = m.optime.t.toNumber(); var output = { Primary : m.name, Elections : t, Date: m.optimeDate,  }}}); use history;  db.history.insert(output));"
```

But I'm getting this error

```
2017-02-20T05:31:25.342-0500 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems: syntax at `\'PRIMARY\'` - you don't have to escape quotes here, at `m.optimeDate,  }` where you don't define document right and at `use history;` - you should not switch db in one `--eval js`` statement.

Instead use `end of file`, like here:

```
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ mongo <<EOF
> var output = 1;
> use history;
> print(output);
> EOF
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
switched to db history
1
bye
```

so in your case it would be:

```
mongo <<EOF
rs.status().members.forEach(function(m) {
  if(m.stateStr === 'PRIMARY') {
    var t = m.optime.t.toNumber(); 
    var output = { Primary : m.name, Elections : t, Date: m.optimeDate};
  }
});
use history; 
db.history.insert(output);
EOF
```

Comment: I'm executing the bash through python. Sorry forgot to mention it, that's why I had to escape it. Thank you very much. EOF works!